# In SQL using Todays date get the week date (mon-sun)

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am stuck and I have not done anything like this before. By providing todays date e.g 2010-12-04, I should get the following:

startdate = 2010-11-29
enddate = 2010-12-05

Basically  I need to filter my query so it gives me data for this 'week'

any idea on how to start this will be great!

Thanks,

Tarun

Comment: I think there is a datename function in SQLServer, you could use that to get "Saturday" from today' date (2010-12-04), and then you could do a select case type of thing. Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate: suggest you search SO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated: This function is due to [Graham at SqlTeam](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=47307).  It returns Monday's date for any given date; it should cope with any `DATEFIRST` setting:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.WeekCommenceMondayDate(@MidWeekDate DateTime)
RETURNS DateTime AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @WeekCommence DateTime
    SET @WeekCommence = DateAdd(d, -((@@DATEFIRST + DatePart(dw, @MidWeekDate) -2) % 7), @MidWeekDate)
    RETURN @WeekCommence
END


declare @today datetime = '2010-12-04' 
declare @weekstartdate datetime

set  @weekstartdate = dbo.WeekCommenceMondayDate(@today)
select @weekstartdate as weekstartdate
select  DATEADD(DD, 6, @weekstartdate) as weekenddate
```

For a variety of date functions see [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=64760).

Comment: ...just need to be careful that SQL Server is configured w/ the right value for DATEFIRST - says me, suggesting a string based solution that dies horribly on a foreign server.  :)

Comment: I think you'll find it works regardless of what DATEFIRST is set to

Comment: Correct based on criteria given but most people consider the week starting on Sunday, ending on Saturday.

Comment: @Mitch: ...assuming that you want the weeks your plucking out to start on the same day as dictated by DATEFIRST?

Comment: @Mitch It returns different results if I run `SET DATEFIRST 1` then your code or `SET DATEFIRST 7`  then your code.

Comment: @Martin: true. See Will A's second comment above.

Comment: I have updated the code above to be agnostic of DATEFIRST setting

Answer (score 1):

The below should work - obviously dependent on when you want weeks to start - and language used so you may need to tweak it.

```
DELCARE @startdate DATETIME = @thedate
WHILE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @startdate) <> 'Monday'
BEGIN
  SET @startdate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @startdate)
END

' @startdate should now be the closest Monday on or prior to @thedate.
```

...@enddate calculation is left as an exercise for the reader.  :)

Comment: @Mitch.  If you can guarantee a particular value for DATEFIRST then I'd agree - I'd probably still use the above, but check DATEPART(WEEKDAY vs. the relevant value.  I wouldn't call it horrendous _then_ - unless it's being called very frequently...

Comment: You can just use `@@DATEFIRST` and adjust accordingly.